# How to ignore the accent color on Windows 10?

Tags: c++, winapi

On Windows 10, you can turn on an accent color on the title bar of windows via Personalization settings.

Could a window of my app ignore that preference and display like if the setting is disabled? All the tricks I found in the web are just drawing own title bar (usually using a framework). Is there no simpler way to do that?

**UPD:** I need to draw an image on the window. The image should be partly inside the rect of the title bar, partly outside. For that reason, I need visually hide the boundary between the title and the client area.

Comment: Why? If I care to select an accent color, surely I want that for all apps.

Comment: @BoP One reason is desire to draw on the title bar area.

Comment: Why would you need to know about this setting when rendering parts of the title bar? Maybe you should instead try to fix *that* code/markup bug?

Comment: @IInspectable Well, I would for same reason that other developers would. VS and VS Code developers, Firefox and Opera developers, MS Office apps developers, even calc.exe developers and the very developers of the Win10 Personalization window.

Comment: Firefox etc. simply use their own custom title bar background color (at least the last time I checked) Ideally, you should figure out what is the title bar color, then match the text color. But I don't know how to find that color, I just give up on title bar customization.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani, thanks for your comment. I've updated the question by adding exactly what I want to do.

Comment: VSCode is open source. So is Firefow. Calc is, too. If you need to know how they do it (whatever *it* is), why not look up how they do it? This question sounds a lot like the [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info). What problem are you really trying to solve?

Comment: @IInspectable Yes, I looked it up. And I took that to account. I believe that is reflected in my question.

Comment: *"Is there no simpler way to do that?"* - From reading the question it is unclear to me what *"that"* is. You may wish to explain the *problem* you are ultimately trying to solve rather than expanding on the [solution](https://xyproblem.info) that doesn't appear to be.

Comment: @IInspectable, sorry for my unclear. I need the title bar and the client area to look like a single canvas, without a hint of a border between them. It's a creative issue. Since I doubted that drawing own title was the standard approach, I asked the question.